# Search for a string in a subject

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using VBA in MSOutlook to search for a string in the subject line and if it is present then prompt a warning.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim strSubject As String
    strSubject = Item.Subject
    If strSubject.Contains("ZAFTM") or Else strSubject.Contains ("BENSP")    Then
        Prompt$ = "operator, Can I send the mail?"
        If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check for Subject") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This gives me an error for invalid qualifier for `strSubject`.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing VB.net syntax with VBA. Strings in VBA are not objects and have no methods.

Use `Instr()` or `Like` in VBA

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim strSubject As String
strSubject = Item.Subject
If strSubject Like "*ZAFTM*" or strSubject Like "*BENSP*" Then

    Prompt$ = "operator, Can I send the mail?"

    If MsgBox(Prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, _
                                           "Check for Subject") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If

End If
End Sub
```